# WSClient and SSL

Tags: java, scala, ssl, playframework

In Play 2.4.3 web app I need to call other service via HTTPS using `WSClient`. I followed [the article](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/WSQuickStart) but the error appears:

> play.api.libs.ws.ssl.CompositeCertificateException: No trust manager
>   was able to validate this certificate chain: # of exceptions = 1

The exception inside `CompositeCertificateException`:

> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

Part of `application.conf` responsible for SSL:

```
play.ws.ssl {
  trustManager = {
    stores = [
      { type : "PEM", path : "C:/A/B/globalsign.crt" }
    ]
  }
}
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem through the following steps:

- Run [InstallCert.java](https://github.com/escline/InstallCert/blob/master/InstallCert.java) to generate `jssecacerts` file.
- Add path to the file in `application.conf`.

Config example:

```
play.ws.ssl {
  trustManager = {
    stores = [
      {path: "C:/A/B/jssecacerts"}
      {path: ${java.home}/lib/security/cacerts}
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: That's fixed my issue, just note that I don't have to continue to 3rd step, once I get jssecacert, it works, and you have to provide the password.